# MySQL Load DATA Query Issue

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Hi I am using `MySQL` LOAD DATA Query to upload my CSV File in to table.
Every time I get the file and need to upload in the table using Query.
My query working fine, But sometime what happen the Sequence of column get change in the CSV file and if Upload that file my column get mismatch.
**My Query:**

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE '/dir/file.csv' INTO TABLE file FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\b' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

How can I make my `LOAD Query` flexible so that Column sequence will not affect my `MySQL Table DATA`

Comment: Your CSV's column order should match the table schema otherwise the upload won't happen.